# How to access the submodule name in omnet++?

Tags: c++, omnet++

For example, I define the module *Sample* in .ned file as follow.

```
simple Sample
{
    parameters:
        @display(...);
    gates:
        inout InOut;
}
```

And then I define two submodules as follow.

```
S1: Sample {
     @display(...);
}
S2: Sample {
     @display(...);
}
```

in .cc file, I define the class *Sample* as follow.

```
class Sample: public cSimpleModule
{
  protected:
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
};
```

Now, how can I access the submodule name in the function *handleMessage*?

For example, I need the following code.

```
void Sample::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    if(strcmp("S1", this->getSubModuleName()) == 0){
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the name of current object (i.e. module, submodule) use `getName()`. However, to check whether the name is equal to a given string one may use convenient method `isName()`, for example:

```
if (isName("S1")) {
    // name is "S1"
}
```

Reference: [OMNeT++ API](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/api/classomnetpp_1_1cObject.html#a3666b57e313a2f38433fdfc50fd94a6b)